# MongoDB Global Timeout Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way ***to apply a global query timeout*** to prevent slow/idle/hanging requests. I don't necessarily need to stop the query, but I need to know if it has been, let's say - 30 seconds and then throw an error back to the frontend UI and log it in the backend.

I found this code in the [mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/#examples) which looks like what I want:

```
db.collection.find({description: /August [0-9]+, 1969/}).maxTimeMS(30000)
```

The only issue here is that I want to apply this `.maxTimeMS(30000)` to all my query's globally and then throw an appropriate error and log it in the backend.

How would I achieve this with Mongo? Not using Mongoose

Comment: don't use find with regexes => it will scan each element in your collection.

Comment: @husanu this was a copy paste from the mongo documentation. This is not my actual query. My question is not one of optimization but how to have a timeout globally on querys and error handling

Answer (score 0):

You can't

After looking in source code of mongodb nodejs driver, seems that there are internal whitelists with options that can be propagated from dbOptions -> collectionOptions -> cursorOptions.

```js
    const db = client.db("foo", { maxTimeMS: 1000 });        /// NOPE
    const coll = db.collection("bar", { maxTimeMS: 1000 });  /// NOPE
    let cursor = coll.find({ name: "asd" }, { maxTimeMS: 1000 }); /// YES
```

so you must call/set maxTimeMS with each query